# How to skip sub directory based on condition in WIX?

Tags: wix

I am using the below code,

```
<Directory Id="dir2" Name="Folder">
   <Component Id="comp_one" Guid="{0D827414-5629-48A0-9DC1-9344C5C6EBFC}">
       <Condition>INSTALLSAMPLES</Condition>
       <File Id="file_one" Source="..\..\..\fileone.exe" />
   </Component>
</Directory>
```

The above code is working fine and skip the `Folder` if condition false.

But in below code `Folder` and `SubFolder` are created, if the `Condition` is false. Is there any solution to skip the directory based on a condition?

```
<Directory Id="dir1" DiskId="3" Name="Folder">
   <Directory Id="dir2" Name="SubFolder">
      <Component Id="comp_one" Guid="{0D827414-5629-48A0-9DC1-9344C5C6EBFC}">
         <Condition>INSTALLSAMPLES</Condition>
         <File Id="file_one" Source="..\..\..\fileone.exe" />
      </Component> 
   </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, from extensive experience, that component conditions don't scale very well.  They are really meant for things like VersionNT and Not VersionNT  where maybe you need to install one DLL/EXE on Win 9X and another mutually exclusive file on NT/2K/XP et al.

Instead you should associate these components to a feature and let the user enable/disable the feature using the Custom Setup dialog.  More complicated abstractions can be made by using Feature Conditions and/or  AddLocal / Remove control events.

The fact that you used a property called INSTALLSAMPLES really tells me you should have a feature called SAMPLES.

Answer (score 0):

Its target folder is part of the "identity" of an MSI component. There is no way to "float" a single component amongst several target folders conditionally. However, you can always define more than component, each targeted to a different folder but sourced from the same file, and conditionally install the one or the other (or both!).

But Mr. Painter knows what he is talking about (on virtually any installer question). Best practice is to condition features (collections of components), not components directly.